# Android Spinner user interaction of on item selected

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have problem in listening user interaction of the spinner when item selected.
I know the below listener work perfect

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // your code here
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}
```

but In my application scenario I will change the spinner value through program,that time also it fire the onitemselected event.but I need this event should fired only when user interaction happened on the spinner

Note:I am not talking on initial spinner value selected item.

Please Let me know how can I accomplish this

Thanks in advance,
Naveenkumar.R

Comment: put code in `onNothingSelected` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tempListener = spinner.getOnItemSelectedListener();
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
//change the spinner value...
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(tempListener)
```

More elegantly, you could subclass the Spinner class, and create 'disableOnItemSelectedListener()' and 'enableOnItemSelectedListener()' methods, which do the same as the code above.

Comment: Its working fine but I need to give some delay before setting the listener back.Let me know if any other solution available without setting the delay

Comment: It has some other problem I have resolved.Now its working without setting the delay.Thank you

Comment: The problem is that the spinner animates and does the callback when it's done. spinner.setSelection(i, false); will disable animation and likewise a delayed callback.

Answer (score 0):

Undesired calls to onItemSelected can be avoided using a simple technique I describe in the following link. This way, you can yourself setSelection anytime without a worry. Check the accepted answer to this question:

[Undesired onItemSelected calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747917/undesired-onitemselected-calls)